# Why did Stack Exchange change the link at the top of the page?

Tags: support, top-bar

The "Stack Exchange" link at the top of the page used to bring up a listing of all the sites I'm a member of.  That was a handy way to quickly visit any of my member sites without separate bookmarks in my browser.  Why did Stack Exchange do away with this handy feature?  I haven't memorized all of the sites I belong to so I have to scroll through the whole list to find my sites.  Seems needlessly complicated.  Please restore this useful feature!

Comment: The site switcher is still there, it’s just switched sides (and is behind an icon, instead of the full logo)

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12692/new-top-bar-is-live-what-does-it-mean-for-me should get you up to speed.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.